# How to make CSS for mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML site and that has some images that I do not want to be seen on a mobile devices or on desktop.

for example:
HTML Code: (index.html)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

//Image for desktop
<img class="desktop" border="0" src="images/logo.png">

//Image for mobile device
<img class="mobile" border="0" src="images/logo-mobile.png">
```

CSS Code: (style.css)

```
/*  #Desktop 
================================================== */
.mobile {
    display: none;
    }


/*  #Mobile 
================================================== */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .desktop {
    display: none;
    }       
}
```

I use this CSS code but does not work.

Comment: Does it also need to change if the browser on desktop gets under 480px? Because if so, this works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Ajr8v/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS3 Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  h1:after {
    content: 'Large screen';
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  h1:after {
    content: 'Medium screen';
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  h1:after {
    content: 'Small screen';
  }
}
```

## [*-DEMO-*](http://jsfiddle.net/92Rnc/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in media queries itself...i used this and it seems to work for me

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:480px)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [**media-queries-for-standard-devices**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

use it like this

```
/*  #Desktop 
================================================== */

    .mobile {
        display: none;
        }
     .desktop {
        display: block;
        }  

    /*  #Mobile 
    ================================================== */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .desktop {
        display: none;
        }    

    .mobile {
        display: block;
        }   
    }
```

For HTC One try

```
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){

}
```

**NOTE** Don't forget to add this inside  tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I put this code, and its work on desktop but dos not work on mobile device. 
INDEX HTML: http://admiral.ba/new/ --- 
CSS CODE: http://admiral.ba/new/css/style.css

Comment: @NetSector try max-width:320px; too  and try changing max-device-width to max-width

Comment: It is the same, i try open with HTC ONE and does not display image "mobile" which is defined.

Comment: NetSector: for HTC One try @media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not resetting the display: none on the .mobile class on mobile screen, and your .mobile class elements will remain hidden. You have to add the following to your media query in order to make the .mobile class visible:

```
.mobile {
    display: block;
}
```

Final coode:

```
/*  #Desktop 
================================================== */
.mobile {
    display: none;
}


/*  #Mobile 
================================================== */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .desktop {
       display: none;
    }       
    .mobile {
       display: block;
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

As I can see, you will have problems to detect which device is a mobile device based on resolution, so I will recommend you to detect it by using the User Agent string, it will have bigger success in your case.

Here is what you should do:
1) Include this in a javascript file loaded on the page:

```
$(document.body).ready(function(){
    var isMobile = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
    if(isMobile) {
       $("html").addClass("mobile-device");
    } else {
       $("html").addClass("desktop-device");
    }
});
```

2) Change your css to:

```
/*  #Desktop 
================================================== */
.desktop-device .mobile {
    display: none;
}


/*  #Mobile 
================================================== */
.mobile-device .desktop {
    display: none;
}
```

This should work for most(maybe 99.9%) of the mobile devices that cand be bought. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I put this code, and its work on desktop but dos not work on mobile device. INDEX HTML: admiral.ba/new --- CSS CODE: admiral.ba/new/css/style.css

Comment: On my HTC One X it displays different images on portrait and landscape, so your media query works! I read your comment on the other response and your mobile HTC One should have 1080 pixels in portrait and 1920 in landscape, so maybe thats why you see the desktop version, because your screen resolution is too big(more than 480px).

Comment: Please check my edited post to see how I would change your code in order to resolve different mobile screen problems in a easy way.

Answer (score -1):

**css:**

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
        .desktop {
             display: none;
        } 
        .mobile {
             display: block;
        }      
    }
```

IT will work. see link http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html